# OpenGL - GLSL - Extract MetalRoughness map to metal map and roughness map?

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

I have a question, I hope it is the right place, I am starting to work with PBR and for this I have started working with the Damaged Helmet model ( https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/DamagedHelmet ).

And my question is, in all the tutorial i have been able to read they speak of metal and roughness as separate textures maps.

In this case I only have a unique texture for metal and roughness.

Is there any way for this texture to extract the roughness map and the metal map?

[MetalRoughness Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quJcu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[glTF 2.0 specs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#pbrmetallicroughnessmetallicroughnesstexture) define Metallic-Roughness texture map as single texture with:

> The metalness values are sampled from the B channel.
>   The roughness values are sampled from the G channel.

So that in GLSL program you need just taking .b and .g components from bound texture.